# Submit form with AJAX and place contents in DIV after jQuery validator

Tags: forms, serialization, jquery

All,
I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#create_review").validate();
    $("#submit_review_link").click(function() {
      if ($("#create_review").valid()) {
        $("#create_review").submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    alert("it is here");
                    $('#created').html(response); // update the DIV
                }
            });
            return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
        });
      }
      return false;
    });
});
```

Here is my actual HTML form:

```
<form action="save_review.php" method="post" name="create_review" id="create_review">
    <textarea name="review" id="review" rows="5" class="required"></textarea>
</form>
<a class="button-2" href="#" id="submit_review_link" onClick="submit_form()">Submit Review</a>
```

I'm trying to validate this and then display the results in my created div. It isn't working but I'm not sure why. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "It isn't working"?  Does the alert pop up?

Comment: @Ivan that is correct. The alert doesn't pop up and nothing goes into the div. In my save_review.php file I just have an echo that says "It works" just to see if the results would populate the div. That doesn't happen either.

Comment: @user1048676: Okay, so which part isn't working? Have you tried debugging? Is the ajax request being sent?  If it is, is it being sent to the right url? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Ivan how can I debug this in this scenario.  I tried an alert before the Ajax function and that didn't display and then I have another alert in the success and that one didn't show either

Comment: How about an `else { alert('Did not validate.'); }` to your `if ($("#create_review").valid())`?

Comment: I did try that and it is validating successfully.

Comment: You can install a debugging plugin like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: @Ivan For some reason it looks like it never makes the ajax call. When I set a breakpoint it goes to the $("#create_review").submit(function() { but then it just jumps down to the second return false and never actually hits the ajax part. Any ideas why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up splitting up these functions and the new code is:

```
$("#create_review").validate();
        $("#submit_review_link").click(function() {
          if ($("#create_review").valid()) {
            submit_form();
          }
          return false;
        });

    function submit_form(){
        data_to_send = $("#review_text").val();
        recipe_id_to_send = $("#recipe_id").val();
        current_reviews = $("#current_reviews").val();
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: {review_info : data_to_send, recipe_id : recipe_id_to_send}, // get the form data
                type: "POST", // GET or POST
                url: "save_review.php", // the file to call
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    update_reviews();
                    $("#review_text").val("");
                    $('#review_saved').prepend(response); // update the DIV
                    if(current_reviews==0){
                        $("#no_reviews").hide();
                    }

                }
            });
            return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking that .submit will submit the form?  All that does is set up a handler for when a submission is created.

You'll still need to submit the form before the callback will happen.

Also, I'm not familiar with the "submit_form" method.  Why not just try it with a normal form submission button instead of a link

http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-submit.phtml

<input type='submit'></input>